# Akka Streams: File Sink does not write stream elements

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm coding a small Akka Streams sample where I want to write elements of a `List` to a local TXT file

```
implicit val ec = context.dispatcher
implicit val actorSystem = context.system
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val source = Source(List("a", "b", "c"))
  .map(char => ByteString(s"${char} \n"))

val runnableGraph = source.toMat(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("~/Downloads/results.txt")))(Keep.right)

runnableGraph.run()
```

The file is already created by the location I set in the code.
I do not terminate the actor system, so definitely it has enough time to write all of `List` elements to the file.

But unfortunately, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the expanded path to your home directory instead of the tilde (`~`). For example:

```
val runnableGraph =
  source.toMat(
    FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("/home/YourUserName/Downloads/results.txt")))(Keep.right)

runnableGraph.run()
```

Comment: Correct. The absolute path works fine! And what if I want to write to a file located in 'resources' directory?